# Regex, need support

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have links:

```
/admin/index.php
/admin/index.php?do=delete_user
/forum/index.php?search=aaa&type=a
/index.php
/index.php?p=home
```

and so on...

How to preg_replace() links that only index.php without GET's will change (if have GET's dont'replace).

Thanks, it's working, but why not working this (?!&), (?!\&)? I want to keep unchange if after asd.aa/index.php?news=1 exist & (asd.aa/index.php?news=1&dont=change)

Comment: I think you need to clarify this, so we can understand exactly what you are wanting.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add the example input and output.

Comment: Please change your title to be more descriptive

Comment: what do you mean with GETs? query string parameters maybe, or actually http get requests?

Comment: Let me try to get this right. You want to replace all links that don't have GET parameters and only index.php to remove the index.php, but if there are GET parameters to leave it alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead: `'/index\.php(?!\?)/'` will match only if there is no `?` after the `index.php`